# MySQL improve query performance

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have such a query:

```
SELECT city.id, city.country_id, localization.lang , localization.name, ... some other fields ...
FROM city city
LEFT OUTER JOIN city_localization localization ON ( localization.city_id = city.id )
WHERE city.country_id = '196' AND localization.lang = 'en'
ORDER BY localization.name
```

"city" table schema:

[image]

"city_localization" table schema:

[image]

Explain output:

[image]

How can I avoid using filesort and temporary?

Comment: I don't know about filesort and temporary, but I've noticed that you filter right side of left join, replacing it in effect with inner join. One should filter `city_localization` in join itself: `LEFT OUTER JOIN city_localization localization ON ( localization.city_id = city.id and localization.lang = 'en')`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create an index for `localization.city_id` and another one for `localization.name` (you currently have one that also includes `localization.lang`).

If you are retrieving a lot of rows you might want to remove `city.country_id` and `localization.lang` from your select, after all you already have those values.